# What are standard (common) ways to draw shapes in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics

Since GLU is considered obsolete for using with modern OpenGL (3.1+), what are the ways for drawing basic shapes such as ellipses or arcs/pies in OpenGL with C/C++? It seems unbelievable that there is not a simple standard or common solution for drawing arcs/ellipses in OpenGL, but to draw then pixel by pixel in 'for' loop. Is there maybe an implementation of GLU using shaders?

Comment: split them into triangles and draw those

Comment: @ratchet - it seems strange to me that there is no a standard solution in some header file for drawing an arc/ellipse in a buffer by calling one function like in Windows GDI and everyone constantly draws every single circle and arc using lines or triangles .

Comment: because the hardware that opengl leverages (by design) is best suited for drawing triangles

Comment: @ratchet - Yes, but there was GLU for the previous versions of OpenGL which was a pretty common way to draw arcs and ellipses.

Comment: which behind the scenes transformed the arcs into triangles to draw

Answer (score 0):

A faster (less trigono) solution in Go (can be easily translated to c++) inspired by this [link](http://slabode.exofire.net/circle_draw.shtml)

Comment: Trignonometric operations are not really THAT expensive these days. And in the link you posted the use of immediate mode (glBegin, glVertex, glEnd) is much a bigger bottleneck than calling sin and cos.